# compose OpenGLRenderer Davey! duration

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

Have noticed in adb logs every second:

```
OpenGLRenderer Davey! duration=9222244663856ms; ...
```

trying to update screen every second in Compose with code:

```
@Composable
fun timerUpdate(delayTime: Duration = 1.seconds): Int {
    var ticks by remember { mutableIntStateOf(0) }

    LaunchedEffect(Unit) {
        while (true) {
            ++ticks
            delay(delayTime)
        }
    }
    return ticks
}


@Composable
fun Greeting() {
    Text(text=timerUpdate().toString())
```

in result all ok, except adb logs flood
duration time looking incredible and may be this message are not valid ?
any ideas how disable this message or may be I'm doing something wrong ?